# set up a static ip adress in my host and vb machine

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I'm running a server on my Virtualbox (Ubuntu 15) and the host is a Win7 machine. I'm shutting down and restart a lot my host machine,so I get various IP addresses on my computer.

Each time I get a new IP adr I have to change various config settings.

Is there a way that I can set "permanent" IP address on my VB and in my host

Comment: Another option is to log in to your router, and *"Reserve an IP Address"* for each device according to its MAC address - this has the benefit that you leave your devices using DHCP and they can attach to any friend's network automatically, but on your own network they will always get the same IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** you can and both are done on a similar way, you just need to get to network administration panel (you can easily get there by right clicking on the network icon at the bottom right on Windows and top right on Ubuntu). Once there, select the interface you are using and set your paramenters to the desire ones.

In case you have no knowledge, firstly check the parameters you get from the DHCP server (`gateway` and `DNS servers`) and use them in your custom configuration (unless you want to change them aswel)

More info:

[Ubuntu](http://www.tecmint.com/set-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-15-10-server/)

[Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/)